# I can't get this function to return true using jQuery UI. It just instantly returns with false

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
function db(a){
                $("#p")[0].innerHTML = a;
                let b = $("#id_start").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: "auto",
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function(){
                            return true;
                        },
                        "No": function(){
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#id_start").dialog("open");
                if (b != true){
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

It just instantly returns false

I am expecting it to return true or false depending on what button is pressed.

Comment: because it is asynchronous. There is no way to wait for the user action from that code. You need to rethink your process to call the next step after the user makes their choice. You can look at using promises also.

Comment: When `db` is called, no button has been pressed. As such, `b` likely doesn't equal `true` or `false`. It's probably `undefined`, or an unresolved promise (I'm not familiar with the plugin). You could have `db` return a promise that is resolved whenever *Yes* or *No* are clicked, but that promise will still not be true or false immediately.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `db`, it will prompt the user to press either *Yes* or *No*. But the user might take a few seconds before they take any action, by then your function has already returned so as to permit the page to continue running other crucial scripts.

This is *asynchronous* behavior, because you are *waiting* for something to take place (i.e. the user clicks a button) before you wish to take further action. As such, we need to write the function in such a way that it defers further action until the user has interacted.

One approach would be to pass-in a reference to a callback function. Then, when the user clicks *Yes* or *No*, we invoke that callback function with either `true` or `false`:

```js
function db ( html, callback ) {
    document.querySelector("#p").innerHTML = html;
    $("#id_start").dialog({
        buttons: {
            "Yes": () => callback( true ),
             "No": () => callback( false )
        }
    });
}
```

Then call it like this:

```js
db( 'Some new markup', response => {
    alert( response ? 'Yes!' : 'No!' );
});
```

Alternatively, you could use a promise:

```js
function db ( html ) {
    document.querySelector("#p").innerHTML = html;
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        $("#id_start").dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Yes": () => resolve( true ),
                "No": () => resolve( false )
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then call it in this manner:

```js
const userResponse = await db( 'new markup here' );
```

In the above scenario, `userResponse` will either be `true` or `false`.